# File Picker - Flutter Building Issue

Tags: flutter, react-native, visual-studio, android-studio

I'm facing this error while building the flutter apk. with VSCode command **flutter build apk**

> 

FAILURE : Build failed with an exception .

- What went wrong :

Execution failed for task ' file_picker : process ReleaseManifest ' .

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks . Process LibraryManifest $ ProcessLibWorkAction > com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2 $ MergeFailureException : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException ; lineNumber : 1 ; columnNu mber : 1 ; Content is not allowed in prolog .

I tried to run flutter build apk command to get debug apk.